# D3js .tsv data not being loaded into variable & attributes

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to draw a simple bar chart using d3js. Here is my `javascript` code for the chart:

```
var width = 420,
    barHeight = 20;

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart")
    .attr("width", width);

d3.tsv("../data/high-court-decisions.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

  chart.attr("height", barHeight * data.length);

  var bar = chart.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
      .attr("height", barHeight - 1);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
      .attr("y", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.value; });
});

function type(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  return d;
}
```

The .tsv which holds the data is in the format:

```
year    decisions
2015    53
2014    52
```

This script is called on the page via: `<script src="../js/hca-bar-chart.js"></script>`.

I am using the d3js v4 min file which is also called via: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`.

There is clearly a problem with the data being loaded into the rectangle "width" attribute. This can be seen once the page loads:

```
<svg class="chart" width="420" height="200">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <rect width="NaN" height="19"></rect>
    <text x="NaN" y="10" dy=".35em">NaN</text>
  </g>
```

As well as the following console error: `Error: <rect> attribute width: Expected length, "NaN".`

Eager for all suggestions to make the bar chart work. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, the javascript file is in its own "js" folder. The .tsv file is in a folder called "data" that can be accessed by going one directory up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `value` header in your data. So, change your accessor function:

```
 function type(d) {
     d.value = +d.decisions;
     return d;
 }
```

Or, alternatively, change your data:

```
year    value
2015    53
2014    52
```

Comment: Oh, I thought ".value" was accessing the value for each key in a dictionary. Not the column of the data source. Cheers!